# When selecting a bow, how can I find out what a good poundage for me would be?

Tags: equipment, archery

I currently have a 30 pound bow which is rather light for me, and I'd like to purchase a new one.  I'm guessing 45-50#, but I'm not sure.  I'm thinking 60# would probably be too heavy (trying to imagine pulling twice the weight of what I have now), but I don't know about that either.  Then again, it might be 40#.  I'm 16 years old, 5' 9", 140 lbs, and not quite in optimal physical condition (~25 pushups straight).

I'm not necessarily asking for you to give me a poundage off of those metrics, but I'd like to know what the right weight should feel like when I'm pulling a bow.  Also, does it matter if I go for a heavier bow, if I'm planning ahead for when (hopefully) I'm more physically fit?  Or should I plan to get a new bow after I "grow out" of the next one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guidance from [huntingnet.com](http://www.huntingnet.com/articles/article_detail.aspx?articles_id=481) is:

> As a rule of thumb, the shooter should be able to comfortably draw the
>   bow back without straining or lifting the bow up over his head in
>   order to draw it back, and hold it back for at least 60 seconds.

They also state that

> Bows in the fifty to seventy pound draw weight will work just fine for
>   most shooters

So if you have been used to a 30 pound bow I would suggest a 50 would be on the upper end of what you would want to move to.

Comment: +1 OK, that makes sense.  I recently talked with a rod-and-gun shop owner, and he asked me if I was using a 45# bow, so that info coupled with your post here gives me a pretty good idea of what I should be looking for.  Thanks!